# LNCS: remove URLs and DOIs from reference

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, urls, lncs, doi

I'm using LNCS style, and natbib with splncs03.bst for references style.
This style shows also URLs and DOIs in references.

Is there any way to remove them without modifying the style and bib file ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please post a minimal working example (MWE): http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Can you go into your bib file and do two global search and replace ops: "doi" -> "xdoi" and "url" -> "xurl"?

Comment: The best choice is to do what Mico suggested. Even if you are able to get rid of them from the preamble, it might be against the LNCS guidelines. So editing the data in the bib file seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as daleif pointed out, the only option is to do what Mico suggested.

Thank you daleif and Mico.

For anyone interested, below is a simple Python script for accomplishing this.
If your bib file formatted differently, change the patterns in *re.sub* arguments.

```
import fileinput
import re
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(files=sys.argv[1:], inplace=1, backup=".bak"):
  if 'url = ' in line:
      line = re.sub('url = ', 'xurl = ', line)

  if 'doi = ' in line:
      line = re.sub('doi = ', 'xdoi = ', line)

  if 'note = ' in line:
      line = re.sub('note = ', 'xnote = ', line)

  print(line.rstrip())
```